# When to Not make Singleton Thread Safe

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton

I'm learning about some design patterns and have discovered the Amazing Singleton!

There seems to be two main ways of implementing the Singleton pattern - one being thread safe (using the `synchronized` keyword) and the other is not thread safe.

My question is, when would one *not* wish to make their singleton thread safe? Even if the original program design does not implement threads, there may be no telling that a future iteration will have that need. Is there a performance penalty when making singleton thread safe? Or some other reason that I'm missing where it is not advantageous to thread-safe a singleton?

Example Thread Safe Singleton:

```
/**
 * Thread Safe Singleton Pattern
 *
 */
public class Database {
    private volatile static H2 uniqueInstance;

    public static H2 getInstance() {
        if (Database.uniqueInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Database.class) {
                if (Database.uniqueInstance == null) {

                    /**
                     * Instantiate First and Only instance of H2
                     */
                    Database.uniqueInstance = new H2();
                }
            }
        }
        return Database.uniqueInstance;
    }
    private Database() {};
}
```

Example Non Thread Safe Singleton:

```
/**
 * Non Thread Safe Singleton Pattern
 *
 */
public class Database {
    private volatile static H2 uniqueInstance;

    public static H2 getInstance() {
        if (Database.uniqueInstance == null) {

            /**
             * Instantiate First and Only instance of H2
             */
            Database.uniqueInstance = new H2();
            }
        }
        return Database.uniqueInstance;
    }
    private Database() {};
}
```

Comment: Considering the proper way to create a singleton in (modern) Java (See: 'Effective Java' by Josh Bloch or [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3)) is to use an `enum` which gives you automatic thread safety re: initialization ... I don't see why you'd ever want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing a program which you know that only you will use and it does not involve `Thread`s then you don't need *synchronization*.

If the **singleton** you are using is immutable or does not have mutable state then you don't need to use *synchronization* either.

So basically it depends on your purposes, its mutable state (or the lack of one) and the possible uses of your **singleton**.

Just as a sidenote: this is common sense it is true for many cases not only for the **singleton** pattern.

Comment: is there a penalty to making it thread safe? it seems "safer" to lean towards going thread-safe just in case it's use changes or someone else tries to use it in a thread...

Comment: Only make it thread safe if you need it. Otherwise it clutters code and it may have an overhead as well. Consider using the classes in the java concurrent packages (like `AtomicInteger`) so you can get rid of the problem altogether. If you really need synchronization you can use `Lock`s instead. Check out the java documentation of the related classes.

Comment: To get rid of the problem altogether, use an `enum` for singletons. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3

Comment: I use `enum`s everytime to implement the singleton pattern. The OP was asking about synchronization however not the implementation details.

Comment: @BrianRoach `enum`s does not solve the synchronization problem when your singleton contains mutable state.

Comment: Hmmm... I was not aware of the `enum` being a perhaps better option. I will look into this for future designs (I love Josh Bloch, his talks are very informative but I have not read his books yet).

Comment: I don't agree with your statement about immutable. Even the singleton is an immutable, you still need to synchronize to ensure another thread don't set the reference after your null check but before your instantiation.

Comment: If it is immutable you can't set anything on it.

Comment: @AdamArold Yes, but I don't set its state. The static field is not of its state.

Answer (score 1):

For standard methods or simple classes without collections, it can be fine to make it synchronized, even if you are not working with multiple threads.  But if you are working with lists, especially, then correctly wrapping the collections to make them synchronized will have a large performance hit.

Here are some basic tips on the performance implications of the synchronized keyword:

http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/synchronization.shtml#REF1

Answer (score 0):

What you have provided an example of is not making the class thread-safe, but making the lazy-initialization of it thread-safe.

In an application server environment obviously any singleton resource needs to tolerate concurrent usage, but you can guarantee that the *initialization during service startup* will be performed by a single thread.  The question to ask yourself is really "does this instance need to be lazily initialized or can I create it during application start-up?"  Other than  faster deployment times, there isn't a huge amount of merit to lazy allocation of resources that are 100% needed to serve requests.